# Query to group by the contents of the field

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel, data-structures

I need help to make query to group by content of field. I have the following Database:

```
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| id | depart_kode  |    depart_task  |            value             |
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| 1  |     001      |  Create Profil  |  Some Value                  |
| 2  |     001.12   |  Create Profil  |  Some Value                  |
| 3  |     001.452  |  Create Profil  |  Some Value                  |
| 4  |     002.914  |  Create Profil  |  Some Value                  |
| 5  |     002      |  Create Profil  |  Some Value                  |  
| 6  |     003      |  Create Profil  |  Some Value                  |
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

I need to make a query where I group by depart_kode and I should print by the first 3 digits like this in format json

```
  "001":[
    {
    "depart_kode":"001,
    and other 
    },
    {
   "depart_kode":"001.12"
    },
    ],
    "002":[
    {
     "depart_kode":"002"
    }
]
```

something like that, most importantly they will be grouped in an array based on the first 3 numbers like 001.
and json just an example, which I want to split into an array based on the first 3 digits

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a database table to a JSON structure?

Comment: You can group by part of field, using substring function.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt no that's just an example, which I want to split into an array based on the first 3 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$departs = [];
foreach ($sqlRows as $row) {
    $departKey = substr($row['depart_kode'], 0, 3);
    
    if (!array_key_exists($departKey, $departs)) {
        $departs[$departKey] = [];
    }
    
    $departs[$departKey][] = $row['depart_kode'];
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/QEl4j).

#### references

- [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - get a specific part of a string (first 3 chars in our example)
- [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-key-exists.php) - checks if the key in an array exists